# Is it safe to store RSA key in a key container, if the encrypted data is stored on the same disk

Tags: windows, security, encryption, rsa

I need to protect sensitive data at rest on a server. To encrypt them I use an RSA keypair generated by the RSACryptographicProvider. Microsoft recommends to store the RSA keys in a key container as described here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/security/how-to-store-asymmetric-keys-in-a-key-container. They also strongly suggest to use Machine level containers against user containers.

However these keys are stored on the file system at a well known location: ...ProgramData\Microsoft\Crypto... protected by file system ACLs. How are these keys protected from leaking in a situation, when someone gains access to the disk itself. In such a situation a potential attacker has access to the entire disk and is able to copy the keys from the filesystem and use them to decrypt the sensitive data.

Is there any additional protection such as those keys being encrypted by something not available on the disk? A TPM key? Anything put by MS to protect the keys?